# asp:button click handler doesn't fire in Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, cross-browser, onclick

I am developing a simple webpage in ASP.NET where on a button click e.g. 'Save' a C# code behind handler function should get called and save the form data.'
The functionality works well with IE and FireFox.
But when I run it with Chrome, the page just makes a postback and never fires the button click event handler in code-behind.
Is this curable by ASP.NET or is there any browser specific setting?
Need help ASAP.Thanx in advance.

Comment: I would be willing to bet that turning on script debugging would tell you the problem.

Comment: In chrome, use the inspect element feature, and click the console tab, this will display errors related to CSS or scripting

Comment: thnx for all your help probably I will get it done from my Colleague.